# Validating OnInput event using JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I am working on a form where I want to add some validation parameters. It is a text field and I want when the user types it validates against a regex. I am using an `OnInput` event. When it fails, the validation parameters a label should be shown when it succeeds the validation parameter is hidden. This doesn't seem to work,,

Please assist?

Markup:

```
<input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="First Name ..." class="input" required>
<label for="fName" id="firstNameErr" style="color: red; font-size: 14px; display: none;">Invalid First Name </label>
```

jQuery OnInput validation:

```
$('#fName').on("input" , function(e) {
     var value = $('#fName').val();
       //Regex
       var fReg = /^[a-zA-Z'` ]+$/i

        //If true hide error label
        if (fReg.test(value)) {
           $("label#firstNameErr").hide();           
         }
        else{
           $('label#firstNameErr').show();
         }
  });
```

Comment: @charlietfl you're right - my bad.

Comment: Does the `<input>` exist when that code runs? Any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: @charlietfl   I have edited my question but it doesnt seem to work,, I am getting this error in console **SyntaxError: missing } after function body note: { opened at line 4, column 37**

Comment: No idea what is on line 4 but you need to fix that error which is blocking the rest of the code

Comment: Please don't edit code in question that changes original intent. Can cause conflict with answers made before the edit

Comment: @charlietfl  Okay Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pure CSS solution

```css
.oninvalid {
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none;
}

:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) + .oninvalid {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="First Name ..." class="input" pattern="^[a-zA-Z'` ]+$" required>
<label class="oninvalid" for="fName" id="firstNameErr">Invalid First Name </label>
```

#### Js way

using jquery [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) because it accepts boolean to show / hide

```js
$('#fName').on("input", function(e) {
  $("label#firstNameErr").toggle(! /^[a-zA-Z'` ]+$/i.test(this.value))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="First Name ..." class="input" required>
<label for="fName" id="firstNameErr" style="color: red; font-size: 14px; display: none;">Invalid First Name </label>
```

Comment: @User683 Thanks Alot,,, what If I have a button for submitting an want to disable it until the input is valid..Is it possible using CSS?

Comment: @Martin form won't submit because of invalid. [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: Using your Js solution,, How can I disable a submit button if the input field is invalid and enable it once the input field becomes valid.

Comment: @Martin what you are asking is something irrelevant to this question. You can find a lot about that online

Answer (score 0):

You need to negate the `match` method. Previously, if it matched you would show the error message but you want it the other way around. Check this [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/panoyumeku/edit?html,js,output).

```
    if (!value.match(fReg)) {
       $("label#firstNameErr").show();           
     }
    else{
       $('label#firstNameErr').hide();
     }
```

Comment: @charlietfl check his first code example, the logic was incorrect and the error message was appearing when the input content was valid.

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't, I only negate the expression `value.match(fReg)` to reverse the result.